# How can I set a node reference programmatically?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes, rules, tokens

I'm trying to write a custom PHP action in [Rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.  Each time after creation of a certain type of content, it should create an additional node with a reference to the created node.( Field by Node reference module )

I've tried to pass the values of nid and/or title of the main node to this field using tokens and it didn't work.

If the field is a text field it passes the variables correctly.

What value should be passed to the node reference field to set it in code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I"ll answer your question, then suggest another way.

Assuming that this is a monolingual site, use

`$additional_node->field_created_node[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid'] = $created_node->nid;`

However, Rules already has actions that can change values on a node, and when you create a node using Rules, it creates a new variable containing the created node. If I were you, I'd just add actions that use that data and not write custom PHP code to do it. I just created one to assign populate a user reference field on a created node (within the same rule) the other day, and it worked fine.